How to install packages with cmake on yocto?
I got a project with several libraries and programs, each using cmake scripts to build them. What I would like to do is define a cmake package, where I define common compiler flags and define a new build type with specific compiler flags ("Coverage" build type with coverage gcc flags).
The "CMakeList.txt" is:

project( VhipBuild )
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.22 )

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
include(GNUInstallDirs)

find_package( boost_coroutine )
# For testing to see if it works
#find_package( VhipBuild )

install(FILES VhipBuild.cmake DESTINATION lib/cmake/vhip)
configure_package_config_file(
        "VhipBuildConfig.cmake.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/VhipBuildConfig.cmake"
        INSTALL_DESTINATION "lib/cmake/vhip/"
)

The "VhipBuildConfig.cmake.in" is like this:
@PACKAGE_INIT@

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VhipBuild.cmake")

check_required_components( VhipBuildConfig )

The "VhipBuild.cmake" is like this:
# define compiler flags for the "Coverage" build type
add_compile_options( "$<$<CONFIG:Coverage>:-g>" )
add_compile_options( "$<$<CONFIG:Coverage>:-Og>" )
add_compile_options( "$<$<CONFIG:Coverage>:-fprofile-arcs>" )
add_compile_options( "$<$<CONFIG:Coverage>:-ftest-coverage>" )

# define compiler flags for the "Coverage" build type
add_link_options( "$<$<CONFIG:Coverage>:--coverage>" )

I am using cmake from yocto kirkstone, and I installed it into "/opt/vhip-testing/". To install these cmake files, I do this:
cmake -B. -S.. --debug-find --install-prefix=/opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/
make install

This installs only "VhipBuildConfig.cmake" and I get following output
Running with debug output on for the `find` commands.
CMake Debug Log at /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_context-1.78.0/boost_context-config.cmake:102 (find_package):
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.78.0/boost_headersConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.78.0/boost_headers-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_coroutine-1.78.0/boost_coroutine-config.cmake:102 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)


CMake Debug Log at /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_context-1.78.0/boost_context-config.cmake:102 (find_package):
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_coroutine-1.78.0/boost_coroutine-config.cmake:102 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)


CMake Debug Log at /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_coroutine-1.78.0/boost_coroutine-config.cmake:102 (find_package):
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_context-1.78.0/boost_contextConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_context-1.78.0/boost_context-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)


CMake Debug Log at /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_coroutine-1.78.0/boost_coroutine-config.cmake:102 (find_package):
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)


CMake Debug Log at /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_coroutine-1.78.0/boost_coroutine-config.cmake:102 (find_package):
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.78.0/boost_headersConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.78.0/boost_headers-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)


CMake Debug Log at /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_coroutine-1.78.0/boost_coroutine-config.cmake:102 (find_package):
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)


CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):
  find_package considered the following paths for boost_coroutine.cmake

    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/Findboost_coroutine.cmake

  The file was not found.

    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_coroutine-1.78.0/boost_coroutineConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/lib/cmake/boost_coroutine-1.78.0/boost_coroutine-config.cmake



CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):


-- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=""
-- CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH=""
-- CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH=""
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local;/usr;/;/opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr;/opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr;/usr/X11R6;/usr/pkg;/opt"
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH=""
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_APPBUNDLE_PATH=""
-- CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR="lib"
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR="/home/dejovivl/ifm-source-code/vhip-sw-devel-ci/cmake/b"
-- CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR="lib"
 CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR =  lib
 CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR =  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dejovivl/ifm-source-code/vhip-sw-devel-ci/cmake/b

If I try find_package( VhipBuild ) in one of my projects, I get this:
 find_package considered the following locations for the Config module:

    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/VhipBuildConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/vhipbuild-config.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/VhipBuildConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/vhipbuild-config.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/games/VhipBuildConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/games/vhipbuild-config.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/VhipBuildConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/vhipbuild-config.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/VhipBuildConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/vhipbuild-config.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/VhipBuildConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/vhipbuild-config.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/games/VhipBuildConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/games/vhipbuild-config.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/VhipBuildConfig.cmake
    /opt/vhip4-testing-sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-ifmlinux-linux/usr/vhipbuild-config.cmake

  The file was not found.



CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindVhipBuild.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "VhipBuild", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "VhipBuild" with
  any of the following names:

    VhipBuildConfig.cmake
    vhipbuild-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "VhipBuild" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "VhipBuild_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "VhipBuild" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):


I looked further, and I found "Findboost_coroutine.cmake" which defines where to find "boost_coroutine-config.cmake". Actually, every cmake package has a Find file in cmake modules.
The questions that I have:

how to modify my CMakeList.txt so it installs both cmake files?
do I have to write a Find cmake file and install it into cmake module directory?
why cmake tries to find my config cmake file in weird locations? ("/", "/usr" and "/usr/games") and how to change that?


I solved it as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/q/64412895/476681 - I set the install pats to "lib/cmake/VhipBuild/" and it magically start to work as expected. Therefore marking this Q as duplicate
